# How to assign html title from variable with vbscript?

Tags: html, asp-classic, vbscript

I'm currently trying to get a modal window to set my html `<title>` from a vbscript function like this:

`<title>` `<%foo.bar%>` `</title>`

where foo.bar

```
Function bar() as string

    bar = "some text"

end function
```

This gives no success.

I also tried the below snippets, but without success. It throws "An unhandled exception" for incompatible types.

```
<%@Language=VBScript%>

<% barVar = "fooFoo" %>

<title><%barVar%></title>
```

Does anyone know what possibly could be the problem here? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to output the value using [`Response.Write()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
<%@Language=VBScript%>

<% barVar = "fooFoo" %>

<title><% Response.Write barVar %></title>
```

or use the shortcut:

```
<%@Language=VBScript%>

<% barVar = "fooFoo" %>

<title><% = barVar%></title>
```

also, I've just noticed that your function definition includes a type, but VBScript does not include explicit typing and everything is a variant. So your function would be

```
function Bar()
    Bar = "some text"
end function
```

Comment: The shortcut worked perfectly, i should've seen that one miles away. Thanks.